# TypeError: (0 , _storeGenerator.storeGenerator) is not a function

Tags: jestjs, babel-jest

I have recently ejected `Create-React-App` and reconfigured many stuff! however, I still can't get the tests working... I get the following error :

```
 TypeError: (0 , _storeGenerator.storeGenerator) is not a function
```

This happens inside `src/store/__mocks__/store.js` where I'm calling a storeGeneratore as below;

```
import storeGenerator from '../storeGenerator';
import TEST_STATE from '../../__mockData__/testState';
import { ROOT_ACTION_TYPES } from './reducers';

const { store, saga } = storeGenerator(TEST_STATE); <-- this line fails 

const resetState = () => {
  store.dispatch({ type: ROOT_ACTION_TYPES.setState, payload: TEST_STATE });
};

export { saga, resetState };

export default store;
```

And here is my jestConfig:

```
module.exports = {
    setupFilesAfterEnv: [
        "<rootDir>/src/setupTests.js"
    ],
    coverageReporters: [
        "html",
        "text",
        "cobertura"
    ],
    snapshotSerializers: [
        "enzyme-to-json/serializer"
    ],
    transformIgnorePatterns: [
        "node_modules/?!(ezyvet-react-ui)",
        "node_modules/?!(ezyvet-fe-helpers)",
        "node_modules/?!(ezyvet-change-management-tools)"
    ],
    moduleNameMapper: {
        "test-utils": "<rootDir>/src/test-utils",
    },
    collectCoverageFrom: [
        "src/**/*.{ts,tsx,js,jsx}",
        "!**/__*__/**/*",
        "!src/**/index.{ts,js}",
        "!src/**/types/*",
        "!src/**/types.ts",
        "!src/react-app-env.d.ts",
        "!src/serviceWorker.ts",
        "!src/setupProxy.js",
        "!src/setupTests.js",
        "!src/test-utils/*",
        "!src/wellnessplan/**/*",
        "!src/main/components/widgetpanel/autoprefix.js"
    ],
    transform: {
        "^.+\\.(js|jsx|mjs|cjs|ts|tsx)$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/babelTransform.js",
        "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
        "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|mjs|cjs|ts|tsx|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js"
    },
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Jest:

**Modules that are mapped to an alias are unmocked by default, regardless of whether automocking is enabled or not.**

This means the mapped module `test-utils`, is trying to import a module that is not mocked, thus the import error.

If you'd wanted to create an alias for your tests like the 'test-utils' I've been trying to do, you should use `moduleDirectories` instead.

`ModuleDirectories` is an array of directory names to be searched recursively up from the requiring module's location. The default value is **node_modules** and in fact this is how Jest imports your third-party libraries into the tests.

Here is an example that will create an alias to a folder named '**utils**':

```
   moduleDirectories: ["node_modules", "utils", __dirname],
```

Here is how my configuration looks like after the changes made:

```
module.exports = {
    setupFilesAfterEnv: [
        "<rootDir>/src/setupTests.js"
    ],
    coverageReporters: [
        "html",
        "text",
        "cobertura"
    ],
    snapshotSerializers: [
        "enzyme-to-json/serializer"
    ],
    transformIgnorePatterns: [
        "node_modules/?!(ezyvet-react-ui)",
        "node_modules/?!(ezyvet-fe-helpers)",
        "node_modules/?!(ezyvet-change-management-tools)"
    ],
    moduleDirectories: ["node_modules", "utils", __dirname],
    collectCoverageFrom: [
        "src/**/*.{ts,tsx,js,jsx}",
        "!**/__*__/**/*",
        "!src/**/index.{ts,js}",
        "!src/**/types/*",
        "!src/**/types.ts",
        "!src/react-app-env.d.ts",
        "!src/serviceWorker.ts",
        "!src/setupProxy.js",
        "!src/setupTests.js",
        "!src/test-utils/*",
        "!src/wellnessplan/**/*",
        "!src/main/components/widgetpanel/autoprefix.js"
    ],
    transform: {
        "^.+\\.(js|jsx|mjs|cjs|ts|tsx)$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/babelTransform.js",
        "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
        "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|mjs|cjs|ts|tsx|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js"
    },
}
```